# find users in mysql db by country using two tables

Tags: mysql

I am trying to modify my live search feature to search two tables. I have two tables members and db_birds. When a user searches, they have the option to show members by country. Table members column country stores the country code, table db_birds stores userID with several other columns but not country. When a query is run it is meant to search for the userID in db_birds, use that number to search in table members to find the person's id and then compare country with what ever country was selected by the person searching.

In simple laymen I have a table setup, so people can add bird shows, it saves all their information. When someone wants to find a listed show in their country, it would search the bird show table, find all the shows and owners. Once it finds the bird show owners, it would then search the bird show owners profiles from the members table to find what country they are in.

This is the query string I was playing about with, I know it is wrong but I have totally tun out of ideas.

```
SELECT memberID, country FROM members WHERE country = "ZW" AND memberID = userID IN (SELECT * FROM db_birds WHERE (title LIKE "%%" OR Species LIKE "%%") AND approvalMsg = "Approved" ORDER BY dateModerated DESC)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the two tables using a shared column (here, memberID and userID). The updated query below should help you achieve your goal:

```
SELECT m.memberID, m.country, db.*
FROM members m
JOIN db_birds db ON m.memberID = db.userID
WHERE m.country = "ZW" 
AND db.approvalMsg = "Approved"
AND (db.title LIKE "%%" OR db.Species LIKE "%%")
ORDER BY db.dateModerated DESC;
```

This query first connects the members table (shortened as m) to the db_birds table (shortened as db) when m.memberID is the same as db.userID. It then filters the results using the country code and search terms for title and Species. Finally, it arranges the results by dateModerated in decreasing order.

Comment: Horaciux, I really appreciate the help, you explained how it works much better than any webpage tutorial I have read so far. I struggled with this for a long time before posting here, but now I am happy I did. Thanks